# Find upper bound time complexity of recurrence function using iterative method

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics

I want to find the upper bound time complexity of this function.

I know how this is done using the induction method, but I can't find clear steps on how to solve it using the iteration method.

$T(n) = 3T(n-1) + \mathcal{O}(1)$ for $n>1$; otherwise $T(n) = \mathcal{O}(1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how you would define the iterative method. A short search on the internet suggested that one should simple write out the first few terms and see if a pattern emerges. First note that being $O(1)$ is just being bounded by some $k$.
$$
\begin{align}
T(1)&\leq k\\
T(2)&\leq 3k+k\\
T(3)&\leq 3(3k+k)+k=3^2k+3k+k\\
T(4)&\leq 3(3^2k+3k+k)+k=3^3k+3^2k+3^1k+3^0k
\end{align}
$$
So it appears we have the pattern
$$
T(n)\leq(3^{n-1}+...+3+1)k
$$
and by the obviously correct statement
$$
(x^{n-1}+...+x+1)(x-1)=x^n-1\\
\iff\\
x^{n-1}+...+x+1=\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}
$$
we see that this is equivalent to
$$
T(n)\leq\frac{3^n-1}{3-1}\cdot k
$$
so that $T(n)=O(3^n)$.

Comment: This is a great explanation, thank you.

Comment: @Dawson: Thank you! And welcome to MSE by the way :)